# preg_replace_callback to replace date inside brackets

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to replace date inside brackets with some text:

`ADB (2010-11) (a)` ----> `ADB : newtext (a)`

```
$output = preg_replace_callback('#\(([\d{4}-d{2}][^)]+)\)#', function ($m) {
          
           return " : ". newtext ." ";
        }, $str);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `preg_replace_callback` for this, `preg_replace` can achieve the goal. You need to fix your regex however. Everything inside `[]` should be a list of characters, ranges separated by `-`s (e.g. `a-z` for ASCII characters between `a` and `z` (not uppercase)), or metacharacters (e.g. `\d` for numbers). The brackets are known as character classes, more can be read about them here https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html.

For what you want you can use:

```
\(\d{4}-\d{2}\)
```

and replace with:

```
: newtext
```

As a PHP line:

```
echo preg_replace('/\(\d{4}-\d{2}\)/', ': newtext', 'ADB (2010-11) (a)');
```

1. Demo: https://3v4l.org/3YKWi
2. Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/zFwvHJ/1/